# Update TableView Cell Height as cell content interaction happens

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UITableView` that contains a number of cells.  In the example below, these two rows each contain a `UICollectionView` that is managing tags.  The initial loading works correctly and the `tableView` resizes the rows correctly based on the UICollectionView height.

[image]

In the `viewDidLoad` method, I have set the following configurations for the `tableView`:

```
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
```

Then, in the `viewDidAppear` method, I call for updates to the `tableView` as follows:

```
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

**PROBLEM 1:** This kind of works, except it animates the increasing of the tableView row height.  Is there a way to fix this only on the initial load?

The second problem is that, if the user interacts with the contents and removes one of them, even though the `collectionView` resizes, it's updated content size is not triggering the `tableView` row to update its height as can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

It could be because it's inside a `tableView` `cell` because normally, the `collectionView` just automatically resizes itself.  See the screenshot below when the `collectionView` is outside of a `tableView`.

[image]

If I scroll the `tableView`, the row is correctly resized as part of the deque/reuse process.  See below:

[image]

I assume part of the problem is that the layout constraints for the `collectionView` when it is inside the `tableViewCell` is that it is pinned to the edges of the `tableViewCell` but unless I do that, then it doesn't display correctly so am lost...

**PROBLEM 2:** How do I fix the tableView row height resizing based on the changes to its contents?

Comment: Typically you set `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` to an estimated height. Most of the time that value doesn't matter. Try something between 44 and 88 (or whatever). Just don't use `UITableView.automaticDimension`. As for when the collection view is updated, you'll need to implement a custom delegate on your collection view that your table view controller can subscribe to. When that delegate method fires your table view controller can call `tableView.reloadRows` for the corresponding table view cell. Give that a shot and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score -1):

Problem **#1** - in `viewDidAppear` use `tableView.reloadData()` instead of `beginUpdates`.

Problem **#2** - call `tableView.reloadRows()` when user interacts with the content of `UICollectionView`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend reloading the whole table view when a single cell is updated. That results in a poor user experience.

Comment: Yes, I would agree about not using `reloadData`.  @Timur - have a look at this video from Apple, particularly at the 30-minute mark... https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/225/?time=41

Comment: @Anthony, thanks for the video! I totally agree with you and Rob - reloadRows is much better solution.